# IIS Error HTTP 500.19: how to solve?

Tags: iis-7.5

after deployed an asp.net application on our internal IIS 7.5 server i got the following error:

> Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error

I've created a virtual directory in the default web server (the one which respond at http://localhost or http://myservername).

I've read at
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934515/en-us
but i don't understand which are the users to add to folder permission. 
I come from iis 6 which needed to add the IUSR user to folder permission.

Where is the error ? Thanks

Comment: This error could be as obscure as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115835/500-19-error-when-running-nuget-gallery-from-iis, in which case the Url Rewrite module was not installed

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently made changes to WSUS, you could try this command:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-[name='xpress']
```

For some reason uninstalling WSUS on my server also broke my default IIS site. This command fixed the issue. I was getting the HTTP 500.19 internal error, and the hex code was 0x8007007e